# angular add string to each number in array in table in component not template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have implemented a function which determines comment based on the result number pushed to array and shows it in a table.

since calling function in template is slowing down performance, how can I get the same result of now without calling the `comment()` function in html??

[Here is stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mdhnnt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

to use the dropdown just click in the input and type either F to get fahrenheit or C to get celsius.

Basically its saving result to localStorage and pushing new result to array (history calculations)

this is the function which i dont like calling in html but cant figure out how to implement it differently inside the component

```
        <td>{{ comment(history.result, history.temperatureUnit === 'C') }}</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a custom pipe:

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'commentResolver'
})
export class CommentResolverPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(temperature: number, isCelsius: boolean): string {
    if (isCelsius) {
      temperature = (temperature * 9) / 5 + 32;
    }
    if (temperature >= 75 && temperature <= 90) {
      return 'Caution: fatigue is possible with prolonged exposure and activity. Continuing activity could result in heat cramps.';
    } else if (temperature > 90 && temperature <= 105) {
      return 'Extreme caution: heat cramps and heat exhaustion are possible. Continuing activity could result in heat stroke.';
    } else if (temperature > 105 && temperature <= 130) {
      return 'Danger: heat cramps and heat exhaustion are likely; heat stroke is probable with continued activity.';
    } else {
      return 'Extreme danger: heat stroke is imminent.';
    }
  }

}
```

Use it like this:

```html
<td>{{ history.result | commentResolver: history.temperatureUnit === 'C' }}</td>
```

[Stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bzicca?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: The issue is that now when i do new calculation, all of the previous calculations comments change to the current one, also when u refresh page the comments disappear

Comment: @mato4899 Oh okay, I'll fix it.

Comment: @mato4899 Fixed. The math seems wrong, however, but that's not the question you asked.

Comment: That works great, thank you. Yeah it can calculate correctly the index only if you input temperature above 26C or 80F but i didnt add the validations to stackblitz